# Calculate the Disk Space with awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am trying to calculate the total disk space on a UNIX (Solaris) host with this script but I have to use awk twice. Is there a better way to do this?

```
> root# iostat -En | grep ^Size 
Size: 146.81GB <146810536448 bytes>     
Size: 0.00GB <0 bytes> 
Size: 107.37GB <107374182400 bytes> 
Size: 107.37GB <107374182400 bytes>
Size: 107.37GB <107374182400 bytes> 
Size: 107.37GB <107374182400> bytes>
Size: 21.47GB <21474836480 bytes>
```

---

Here is the awk syntax I am applying:

```
    # iostat -En | grep ^Size | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d"G" -f1  | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'

> 29412.7
```

Can we add a scaler as well to have the values in better format for decimal presentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awk will select for `^Size` lines (eliminating `grep`) and remove the `G` for you:

```
iostat -En | awk '/^Size/{sum+=$2} END {print sum}'
361.55
```

The expression `sum+=$2` forces awk to treat the second field as a number.  This means that alpha characters are removed.

#### More accurate calculation

The third field in your `iostat` output appears to contain actual bytes.  That eliminates the need to convert gigabytes, megabytes, etc.  To use this field:

```
iostat -En | awk -F'[ \t<>]+' '/^Size/{sum+=$3} END {printf "%sGB\n", sum/1e9}'
361.559GB
```

The option  `-F'[ \t<>]+'` tells awk to treat any combination of space, tab, or angle brackets as field separators.  This has the effect of removing the `<` and `>` from the third field so that the third field can be directly treated as a number.

#### More on awk's variable conversion

One can directly test awk's conversion from string to number with commands like:

```
$ echo '132G' | awk '{print $1+0}'
132
$ echo '<132G' | awk '{print $1+0}'
0
```

In the latter case, the `<` caused the conversion to number to fail.  That is why the field separator was changed in the code above to remove the `<` from the fields.

Comment: this is not working

`root-> iostat -En | awk '/^Size/{sum+=$2} END {print sum}'


0



root-> iostat -En | grep ^Size | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d"G" -f1  | awk '{sum+=$1} END {print sum}'


14066.2`

Comment: This does not yeild any output though..

`root-> iostat -En | awk -F'[ \t<>]+' '/^Size/{sum+=$3} END {printf "%sGB\n", sum/1e9}'
0GB`

Comment: Just to add shell is ksh (/bin/ksh)

Comment: On Solaris, use `nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`. Never use `/usr/bin/awk` -- it's known as "the old broken awk"

Comment: @ Glenn - yes you are correct , that was the problem . Though i see,
Solaris is well known for the fact that the some commands under /bin /usr/bin are not POSIX compliant. Instead they have additional compliant versions under /usr/xpg4 and similar hierarchies.

Comment: @John1024 - nice explanation. Whats is that "sum/1e9" means.

Comment: `sum` is in bytes.  The output is in gigabytes.  To convert bytes to gigabytes, we divide bytes by 1,000,000,000 which is 1 followed by nine zeros or, in computer notation, `1e9`.  Hence, we write `sum` divided by `1e9` or `sum/1e9`

Answer (score 0):

John1024's simple answer will work with the sample output you provided but might miss some disks in the general case. There is actually no guarantee for `Size` to be the first token to appear in `iostat` output, e.g.:

```
# iostat -E
cmdk0     Soft Errors: 0 Hard Errors: 0 Transport Errors: 0
Model: VBOX HARDDISK   Revision:  Serial No: VB7dd0d7cc-4f38 Size: 34.36GB <34359607296 bytes>
Media Error: 0 Device Not Ready: 0 No Device: 0 Recoverable: 0
Illegal Request: 0
```

Here is then a reliable way to compute the size of attached devices by extracting the size in bytes wherever it appears on `iostat` output:

```
iostat -E | nawk '/Size:/ {
  sub(".*Size:[^<]*<",""); # Remove the leading part of the line up to the first "<" following "Size:"
  sub(" bytes>.*$","");    # Remove the trailing part of the line "from bytes>"
  sum+=$0                  # The line now only contains the size in bytes, sum it to the previous ones (if any)
  cnt++                    # Count the number of devices
}   
END {
  print cnt,"devices:"
  # Print the size:
  # - in gigabytes (1 GB = 1000000000 bytes = 10^9 bytes)
  # - in gibibytes (1 GiB = 1024*1024*1024 bytes = 2^30 bytes)
  # - in bytes
  printf("%0.3f GB (%.3f GiB, %s bytes)\n",sum/1e9,sum/2e30,sum);
}'
```

Comment: .. this solution works.. can you please explain this code, as i am a newbie to coding , would appreciate any explanation. Specially the below line..




`printf("%0.3f GB (%.3f GiB, %s bytes)\n",sum/1e9,sum/2e30,sum)`